# Dynamically checking two checkboxes to select one radio button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying all weekend to solve this problem I may be overcomplicating it. The simplfied code that I'm working is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated - as I'm racking my brains with this for a long while now.

**Problem**: Upon checking of two checkboxes, the respective radio button is selected. So selecting Earth and Wind checkboxes will select the 'Earth and Wind' radio button.

```
<input name="single" type="checkbox" id="Earth"/>Earth<br>
<input name="single" type="checkbox" id="Wind"/>Wind<br>
<input name="single" type="checkbox" id="Emotion"/>Emotion<br>
<input name="single" type="checkbox" id="Grass"/>Grass<br>
<input name="single" type="checkbox" id="Good"/>Good<br>

<hr>

<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Earth Wind"/>Earth and Wind<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Earth Emotion"/>Earth and Emotion<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Earth Grass"/>Earth and Grass<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Earth Good"/>Earth and Good<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Wind Emotion"/>Wind and Emotion<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Wind Grass"/>Wind and Grass<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Wind Good"/>Wind and Good<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Emotion Grass"/>Emotion and Grass<br>
<input name="pair" type="radio" class="Emotion Good"/>Emotion and Good<br>
```

EDIT: To evidence, my efforts: http://jsfiddle.net/rsF6w/: where I've also disabled the checkboxes after two are checked.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to attach event handlers to the `onClick` events. Inside these functions you will grab all of the box's states. In the event that two states are checked you will check the appropriate radio button. This is a good problem to solve. Complete code would soil the learning experience.

Comment: thank you  [http://jsfiddle.net/rsF6w/](http://jsfiddle.net/rsF6w/) I've got this far, but am stuck. Any advice would be very helpful thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can give each checkbox a code which use the bit mask. Then do a OR comparison to get the bit code of the radio button to select.

Read this for more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

For example, earth will have the code corresponding to 00000001, wind : 00000010, emotion 00000100, etc.

Earth wind will get the code : 00000011

Answer (score 0):

Go through all checkboxes (with *for*, for example) and get which two are checked. Create two strings, which would be the same as the desired radio button's name (concatenate them in both directions). This time go through the radio buttons, and if you find a matching name, check it.

Make sure you handle exceptions, like selecting >2 checkboxes at once, not selecting a valid pair (you won't check anything, might as well do it with a boolean), etc.